# auto_increment_increment issue CRM-7923

Tags: wordpress, database, installation, hosting

My activation of CiviCRM WordPress plugin was halted by database error message:

> "An auto_increment_increment value greater than 1 is not currently
>   supported. Please see issue CRM-7923 for further details and potential
>   workaround."

Have searched for number string 7923 but without any results. Does anyone here remember this issue or the potential database workarounds so that I can raise a focussed support ticket for my hosting supplier, please? It's one of just three red stripes remaining on the plugin installation screen. (One is a permissions issue, the other is about database triggers and may clear itself if I can resolve the auto_increment_increment issue. Otherwise, I've got green lines for the rest, which is good to go.)

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of this before, but did track down the issue for you:

[CRM-7923: Installation procedure relies on contiguous auto increment ids](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7923)

Read the thread more closely to be sure, but from a glance it looks like this command may be needed in your hosting environment:

```
cd sites/all/modules/civicrm/sql
sed -i '1i\SET SESSION auto_increment_increment=1;\nSET SESSION auto_increment_offset=1;' *.mysql
```